# PostgreSQL Insert multiple row if not exist

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert rows into a two column table,PRODUCTS_CAT, if the rows don't exist already, through my java application. The rows are read from xml queues.

This is the method in which I get the queues.

```
public void syncProduct(final ProductInfoExt prod) throws BasicException {
    Transaction t = new Transaction(s) {
        public Object transact() throws BasicException {
            // Sync the Product in a transaction

            // Try to update
            if (new PreparedSentence(
                s,
                "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET REFERENCE = ?, CODE = ?, NAME = ?, PRICEBUY = ?, PRICESELL = ?, CATEGORY = ?, TAXCAT = ?, IMAGE = ? WHERE ID = ?",
                SerializerWriteParams.INSTANCE).exec(new DataParams() {
                    public void writeValues() throws BasicException {
                        setString(1, prod.getReference());
                        setString(2, prod.getCode());
                        setString(3, prod.getName());
                        // setBoolean(x, p.isCom());
                        // setBoolean(x, p.isScale());
                        setDouble(4, prod.getPriceBuy());
                        setDouble(5, prod.getPriceSell());
                        setString(6, prod.getCategoryID());
                        setString(7, prod.getTaxCategoryID());
                        setBytes(8, ImageUtils.writeImage(prod.getImage()));
                        // setDouble(x, 0.0);
                        // setDouble(x, 0.0);
                        setString(9, prod.getID());
                    }
            }) == 0) {
                // If not updated, try to insert
                new PreparedSentence(
                        s,
                        "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME, ISCOM, ISSCALE, PRICEBUY, PRICESELL, CATEGORY, TAXCAT, IMAGE, STOCKCOST, STOCKVOLUME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                        SerializerWriteParams.INSTANCE)
                        .exec(new DataParams() {
                            public void writeValues() throws BasicException {
                                setString(1, prod.getID());
                                setString(2, prod.getReference());
                                setString(3, prod.getCode());
                                setString(4, prod.getName());
                                setBoolean(5, prod.isCom());
                                setBoolean(6, prod.isScale());
                                setDouble(7, prod.getPriceBuy());
                                setDouble(8, prod.getPriceSell());
                                setString(9, prod.getCategoryID());
                                setString(10, prod.getTaxCategoryID());
                                setBytes(11, ImageUtils.writeImage(prod
                                        .getImage()));
                                setDouble(12, 0.0);
                                setDouble(13, 0.0);
                            }
                        });
            }
                    /* Insert in catalog */
            new StaticSentence(
                    s,
                    /*
                     * leyonce - Insert into the product catalog if the
                     * products aren't already there
                     */
                    "INSERT INTO  PRODUCTS_CAT(PRODUCT,CATORDER) SELECT  ?,NULL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT (?,NULL) FROM PRODUCTS_CAT)  ",
                    SerializerWriteString.INSTANCE).exec(prod.getID());
            return null;
        }
    };
    t.execute();
}
```

The first row is inserted and all other rows are not. It apparently does the insert if the table is empty.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I can't see any _other rows_ in the code you provided.

Comment: I'm not sure i understood what you meant. The rows are read from a queue in xml file format. Should I include that too?

Comment: I understood this: `prod` contains the data of one row, and the code you provided is called multiple times, one time per row. If I'm right, are you sure if your code is really called multiple times? If I'm wrong, can you show the class that holds all the rows?

Comment: yes I'm sure it's called multiple times. If i perform an insert without the where condition,INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_CAT VALUES (?, NULL)  it includes all the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(SELECT (?,NULL) FROM PRODUCTS_CAT)` always exists (return a row) as soon as there is a row in `PRODUCTS_CAT`. To test if this id is already inserted, you should do:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM PRODUCTS_CAT WHERE PRODUCT = ?
```

Full insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO  PRODUCTS_CAT(PRODUCT,CATORDER) SELECT  ?,NULL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PRODUCTS_CAT WHERE PRODUCT = ?)
```

---

Also you need to bind the id to each question mark "`?`":

```java
new StaticSentence(
    s,
    "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_CAT(PRODUCT,CATORDER) SELECT ?,NULL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PRODUCTS_CAT WHERE PRODUCT = ?)",
    new SerializerWriteBasic(Datas.STRING, Datas.STRING)
    ).exec(prod.getID(), prod.getID());
```

Comment: Yes it tests if that Id already exists but if I try to insert once again the same row plus others it returns an error and doesn't insert the other rows.

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_cat_pkey"
  Detail: Key (product)=(138) already exists.

Comment: @Leyonce It may be that only one placeholder `?` matches the id parameter. Try with something like `.exec(prod.getID(), prod.getID())`. What library do you use?

Comment: I'm using java.sql*.I tried the .exec(prod.getID(), prod.getID()).The app loads forever. I did not understand the one placeholder thing could I have some references?

Comment: There is no `StaticStatment` nor `SerializerWriteString` in `java.sql`, so you're using something else. I can't show references of a library I don't know. The point was about the two question marks "`?`" in your INSERT request. It seems obvious that `prod.getID()` will "replace" the first question mark. But I suppose that `null` will replace the second question mark, leading to your problem. How did you actually wrote the `.exec(prod.getID(), prod.getID())` thing? (And do you happen to use something called "mbpos" ?)

Comment: Nope I'm not using anything called "mbpos". Here are the libraries I'm using. It's actually StaticSentence, I made a silly mistake.                           `com.openbravo.data.loader.SerializerWriteString com.openbravo.data.loader.PreparedSentence com.openbravo.data.loader.StaticSentence`

Comment: I wrote exactly  the `.exec(prod.getID(), prod.getID())` thing

Comment: @Leyonce You have to adapt a little bit your code for two arguments. (`SerializerWriteString.INSTANCE` doesn't seem to allow two arguments.) I updated the answer with some code that should work, but I can't test it myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60852/discussion-between-leyonce-and-volune).